# Get selected option value of select tag inside a td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a select option tag in a table dynamically and while submitting  I'm iterating the table tr to find the element in the td. It returns me the select tag as string itself. Here I'm not able to get the selected option of select tags

My code is

```
$('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {   
       var countryTag = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(); // return the whole select option as string
       var selCntry = countryTag.find('option:selected').val(); // this is throwing error.
 }
```

But while adding select tag to table , selected attribute is not available to any option.

How can I get all selected countries

P.S : this post is made via mobile. So there may be any typo

Comment: Can you share the HTML Code.?

Comment: html code is not required as the select tag is getting binded using javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try something like this:

```
$('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {   
    var tdObject = $(this).find('td:eq(2)'); //locate the <td> holding select;
    var selectObject = tdObject.find("select"); //grab the <select> tag assuming that there will be only single select box within that <td> 
    var selCntry = selectObject.val(); // get the selected country from current <tr>
});
```

Comment: Excellent. Right one.

Comment: Whats the problem? _Could you please try something like this:_

Comment: Actually OP was trying to fetch selected country from `html` string. Instead of that we can do it very straight forward way like above which also very much easy to maintain in long run.

Answer (score 3):

Thats because your are calling the function `html()` on it, you can only call `find()` on the jquery element

Use

```
$('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {   
       var countryTag = $(this).find('td:eq(2)'); // return the whole select option as string
       var selCntry = countryTag.find('option:selected').val(); // this is throwing error.
 }
```

or you can do it in a single command like

```
 $('#tableid tbody tr').each(function() {   
       var value = $(this).find('td:eq(2) options:selected').val(); // return the whole select option as string

 }
```